# Segmentation fault in a nested loop for doing calculations using each 2 elements in vector

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, openmp

I have a very time consuming function, which needs to so some calculation using each 2 elements in a `std::vector`. The way I am doing now is,

```
std::vector<int> vec;
for (auto it = vec.begin(); it != vec.end(); ++ it)
  for (auto it2 = vec.begin(); it2 != vec.end(); ++ it2)
    if (it2 != it)
      f(*it, *it2) // the function
```

I am wondering if there are any other better ways to do this, because this process cost too much time.

Besides, I have tried to use OpenMP to parallelize the outer loop, it works fine when I use `std::vector`, but if I do similar things with `std::map`, it returns a segmentation fault.

---

Updates for the parallel for loop.

The thing I am doing is calculate music similarity using music tags. The tags of each music is in a `std::map` called `map_tag`, and all song ids are in a `vector` called `song_vec`. I did not use `iterator` here, the major part of my code is below. It seems the problems happen when reading the data from `map_tag`, because if I remove this part the parallel loop works fine.

```
unsigned int finishCount = 0;
std::map<std::string, std::vector<std::string>> map_tag;

#pragma omp parallel shared(finishCount) num_threads(2)
{
    #pragma omp for
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < numOfDoc; ++ i) // numOfDoc is number of music
    {
        std::string song_id = song_vec[i];
        std::vector<std::string> song_tag;
        song_tag = map_tag[song_id]; // problems here

        for (std::size_t j = 0; j < numOfDoc; ++ j)
        {
            std::string song_id2 = song_vec[j];
            std::vector<std::string> song_tag2;
            song_tag2 = map_tag[song_id2]; // problems here

            if (song_id != song_id2) 
                calSimilarity(song_tag, song_tag2);
        }

        // so somethings here

        #pragma omp critical // use this show progress
        {
            finishCount ++;
            cout << finishCount << "\r";
            cout.flush();
        }
    }
}
```

---

Another update, I have add `#pragma omp critical` before the problem part, and the program can work correctly. I am not understand how the fault was caused, because the `map_tag` is a read only variable, it can not be modified inside the loop.

I am very new to C++, thanks for all of your kindly help.

Comment: You said it worked when you used `std::vector`, so I'm not sure what your problem is because you are using `std::vector`. Can you clarify?

Comment: @Sam He says it costs too much time.

Comment: He said he used OpenMP to parallelise it with the `std::vector`. It's not clear to me what the problem is.

Comment: If `f` is a time consuming function, then are you sure the nested loops are a bottleneck? Have you tried generating another `vector` derived from `vec` that contains all possible pairs of inputs and iterating over it 2 elements at a time?

Comment: *"but if I do similar things with `std::map`"* - then copy from the map to a `vector` first... it's likely relatively cheap (will have better memory locality than the map during OpenMP parallel processing).  I'm not necessarily advocating expanding all the permutations as Praetorian suggests, though that's worth a try for sure.

Comment: Thanks, I will try to use `vector` instead of the `map`. Besides, I want to know if there are ways better than the nested loop for doing things like this?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, change this:

```
std::vector<int> vec;
for (auto it = vec.begin(); it != vec.end(); ++ it)
  for (auto it2 = vec.begin(); it2 != vec.end(); ++ it2)
    if (it2 != it)
      f(*it, *it2) // the function
```

To this:

```
std::vector<int> vec;

/// hopefully fill vec with something here... :(

for (auto it = vec.begin(); it != vec.end(); ++ it)
  for (auto it2 = next(it); it2 != vec.end(); ++ it2) /// SEE INITIAL IT2 VALUE
      f(*it, *it2) // the function
```

And you've reduced your iterations by MORE than half.

You're doing a lot of duplicate work. Each inner loop calls `f()` for `vec.size()-1` times.

Start there, see where it takes you. Also, nothing in your question is OpenMP specific, and I can't tell where your parallelization is happening. Please update with more code or detail.

Comment: Say vec contains `{ 1, 2 }`, the original code will execute `f(1,2)` and `f(2,1)`, but yours doesn't - you could have a second `f(*it2, *it)` inside the loops to do so.

Comment: Yes, I understand what you mean about the duplicate work. Actually, the function `f(*it, *it2)` have a return value, and I need the return value to do something else. I have tried to use something like `std::map<std::set<int, int>, double>` to save the return value, where *it and *it2 are in the `set`, so that I don't need to calculate everything twice. But if the `vec` is very large, this method will cost a large amount of memory.

Comment: @ZhaojieTao Okay. Why do you need to store the return value and revisit it, rather than just doing whatever processing you need? If you need to store N items, you're going to have to consume N * sizeof(type(N)) memory, regardless of what collection you use. (Ignoring swapping to out-of-core, etc.)

Comment: @TonyD OP said he needed to perform an operation on each pair of values, and did not specify that it was order-dependent. In that case, he'd still be better off calling `f(a,b)` and `f(b,a)` within the body of the innermost loop.

Comment: Thanks, I will reconsider my logic.